# HTML CSS No Color Showing

Tags: html, css, web, colors

The CSS colors I am selecting won't show up and I don't know if its a glitch or my error but I've checked everything.

```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   header {
     backround-color: #00795;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 40px 0;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
   }
   nav ul {
     backround-color: #43a286;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
   }
   a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit;
   }
   nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 20px;
   }
   nav ul li:hover {
     backround-color: #399077;
   }
   section {
     line-height: 1.5em;
     font-size: 0.9em;
     padding: 40px;
     width: 75% margin 0 auto;
   }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Best Website Since Google </h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>

    <a href="#">
      <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>About</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Blog</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Shop</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Gallery</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Contact</li>
    </a>

  </ul>
</nav>


<section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
  Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean
  quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum.
  Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis,
  tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit.
  Sed lectus.Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia
  molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices
  ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim
  in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit
  orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales.
</section>
```

Comment: *backround-color:* It is `background-color`

Comment: Also, your html is invalid. You cannot wrap list-items in anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `color:` is for text.

And `background-color:` is for background's

You have just made a spelling mistake.

---

Now onto your html:

Put your `<a>` inside your `<li>`

Put your `<nav>` inside your `<header>`

Also you cant use `<section>` unless it has an h tag at the beginning of it.

Plus You don't seem to be sectioning a document or an area of your site it just appears to be used as a wrapper which it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a "g" in `background-color` my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nwkfvt49/10/

Comment: Your answer is not the correct answer, he already knew how to use `background-color:` it is in his code, what you FAILED to mention is his syntax error on the spelling of `background-color:`, So yeah your "answer" DID NOT answer the question.

Comment: @DCdaz take the "points" IDC I am here to help and I do not care about my "rep", actually why don't you mark my answer down and then flag it? Troll